# JSDoc: declare @type for variable in "for...of" loop

Tags: javascript, types, ecmascript-6, annotations, jsdoc

Can I declare type for variable ***one*** using JSDoc `@type` annotation?

```
/** @type some.type */
for (let one of many) {
    ...
}
```

Something like PHPDoc annotation:

```
/** @var \Some\Type $one */
foreach ($many as $one) {

}
```

Comment: I don't think I'd normally expect type declarations inside a function. Wouldn't you look at the documentation for whatever created `many`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth , I use PHPDoc `@var` annotations in any place of my code to annotate the type of any variable. Can I do the same with JSDoc?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can. You just have to move the type declaration inside of the parentheses, before your variable:

```
for (/** @type {SomeType} */ const one of many) {
    // ...
}
```

This works just fine, although I usually prefer specifying the type of `many` instead. For instance:

```
/** @type {Number[]} */
const many = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

And then the type of `one` will be automatically inferred.

*P.S.: notice I declared `one` as `const`. Despite of what one may guess, you can declare `for..of` loop variables as constants!*

Comment: I have the following `for`: `for(/** @type {string} */ let event of JSON.parse(msg))`. `event` is still `any` rather than `string`, so this method doesn't seem to work (at least everytime). I tried to use `string[]` for `JSON.parse(msg)`, but `event` is still `any`

Comment: I had to move the JSDoc AFTER the const
```for (const /** @type {SomeType} */ one of many)```